# Keeping a rake job running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, bash, background

I'm using `delayed_job` to run jobs, with new jobs being added every minute by a cronjob.

Currently I have an issue where the rake jobs:work task, currently started with 'nohup rake jobs:work &' manually, is randomly exiting.

While God seems to be a solution to some people, the extra memory overhead is rather annoying and I'd prefer a simpler solution that can be restarted by the deployment script (Capistrano).

Is there some bash/Ruby magic to make this happen, or am I destined to run a monitoring service on my server with some horrid hacks to allow the unprivelaged account the site deploys to the ability to restart it?

Answer (score 0):

The `delayed_job` docs suggest that you use a monitoring service to manage the rake worker job(s). I use runit--works well.

(You can install it in the mode where it does not replace init.)

Added:

Re: restart by Capistrano: yes, runit enables that. Just do a

> sudo sv kill delayed_job

in your Capistrano recipe to kill the delayed_job worker. Runit will then restart it with your newly deployed code base.

Answer (score 0):

For me the daemons gem was unreliable with delayed_job.  Could be a poorly written script (was using the one on collectiveidea's [delayed_job github page](http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/82c9740d0004003ca4a81500401010b95898fd57/lib/delayed/command.rb)), and not daemons fault, I'm not really sure.  But for whatever reason, it would restart inconsistently on deployments.

I read somewhere this was due to it not waiting for the process to actually exit, so the pid files would get overwritten or something.   But I didn't really bother to investigate.  I switched to the daemons-spawn gem using [these instructions](http://rwldesign.com/journals/1-solutions/posts/24-working-with-delayed-job) and it seems to be much more reliable now.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented small rake task that restarts the jobs task over and over again:

```
desc "Start a delayed_job worker in a endless loop to prevent exits."
task :jobs => :environment do
  while true
    begin
      Delayed::Worker.new(:min_priority => ENV['MIN_PRIORITY'], 
                          :max_priority => ENV['MAX_PRIORITY'], 
                          :quiet => false).start
    rescue Exception => e
      puts "Exception occured (#{e})"
    end
    puts "Task jobs:work exited, clearing queue and restarting"
    sleep 1
    Delayed::Job.delete_all
  end
end
```

Apparently it did not work. So I ended with this simple solution:

```
for (( ;; )); do rake jobs:work --trace; done
```

Answer (score 0):

get rid of delayed job and use either [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) or [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque)